# Iterate through MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to make an address book with C# and MySQL Database. I'm trying to use labels and set the `Text` of the `Label` with the database info. I'm using a `FlowLayoutPanel` for my labels. I'm only getting 1 persons information to show, I want all of the people in the database to be listed in the output. What am I doing wrong?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT first_name, last_name, street, city, state, zip, phone, email From address_book ORDER BY last_name, first_name";
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lblFirstName.Text = reader.GetString("first_name") + " " + reader.GetString("last_name");
        lblStreet.Text = reader.GetString("street");
        lblCityStateZip.Text = reader.GetString("city") + ", " + reader.GetString("state") + " " + reader.GetString("zip");
        lblPhone.Text = reader.GetString("phone");
        lblEmail.Text = reader.GetString("email");
    }        
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You only have one set of UI elements, and you're repeatedly writing to just that one set.  Whatever UI technology you're using, you're going to want some kind of repeater or list or grid UI component which displays *multiple* records.  You can't display multiple records with only one label.

Comment: yes @David is correct you need some repeater or grid to show based on the return numbers of rows from your query.

Comment: You may have a FlowLayoutPanel, but controls like `lblFirstName` don't know anything about what container they are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to write the code I wanted. I'm using a `label` on a `FlowLayoutPanel` to write all the entries in the MySQL table. This is not a Windows Form `Label` from the toolbox. It will write from the database to the `label` repeatedly and the `flowLayoutPanel` will place each new output one after another in the `panel`.

```
cnn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Label lblName;
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                lblName = new Label();
                lblName.Text = reader.GetString("first_name") + " " + reader.GetString("last_name") + " \r\n"
                + reader.GetString("street") + " \r\n"
                + reader.GetString("city") + ", " + reader.GetString("state") + " " + reader.GetString("zip") + " \r\n"
                + reader.GetString("phone") + " \r\n"
                + reader.GetString("email");
                lblName.Width = 200;
                lblName.Height = 90;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblName);
            }

            cnn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can see the last retrieved record in the labels because each time the next retrieved record overwrite the `Label`'s `Text` in the `while` loop. If you want to show the all retrieved records you should use [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx). Something  like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT first_name, last_name, street, city, state, zip, phone, email From address_book ORDER BY last_name, first_name", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I need more information on how to use this. In Java using a label in the loop works well but I'm not understanding how to do it in c#. SqlDataAdapter is underlined and it says "The type or namespace 'SqlDataAdapter' could not be found" and dataGridview1 is underlined and says "The name dataGridView1 does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @DaleWahl...You should add `DataGridView` from toolbox to your form. Also add `using System.Data.SqlClient;` to using directive.

Comment: I figured out how to use labels in the loop, it's very similar to Java. I got DataGridView working but I couldn't get it to look the way I want it.